# 16x40 Stick Frame on Monolithic slab - Should it be designed professionally?

Tags: framing, frame

I will be building a 16x40 stick frame building on a monolithic slab.  2x6 walls that are 12 feet high with 16 inch spacing for the studs.  The roof would have trusses at 2 feet spacing.  I would use OSB on the exterior walls and roofing sheathing on the trusses.  I would use L bolts to anchor the framed walls to the slab (12 inches from the corners/ board ends, and maybe every 4 feet).  My question is not about the building process or steps.

I am concerned that I don't know something that I would need to know to frame and exterior of a 40 foot wall.  That I may not know how to frame the building in a way that will last and withstand winds + snow.  Is there value in having someone design/plan the 2x6 framing so that the building is sturdy and stable? Or is it just a matter of building 12 foot wall sections, putting them up with a top plate that overlaps the sections, then having 5/8" L bolts at the appropriate spacing?

Comment: Your user name indicates that this will be used in a commercial setting. As such, you're opening yourself to liability for damage and, potentially, lawsuits should someone be injured in your building. You will also have to carry some sort of commercial insurance on the building and _might_ not be able to get it or have to pay significantly more if there isn't an architect's or engineer's stamp on the plans.

Comment: It's not a 40-foot wall. It's a 12 foot wall. The roof structure supports the top and the foundation supports the bottom, laterally speaking, so that's the only dimension that really matters. The building could be a _mile_ long and this wouldn't change. That said, your question is rather vague. Yes, experts tend to be expert at what they do. If that part of thie question is just a distraction, consider reformulating to be more clear. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: So 40 feet horizontally. For the wall itself, standard 2x4 on 16" centers ought to be fine unless it's carrying an unusual amounts of weight -- it works for houses, after all. That presumes other parts of the structure brace it in other directions, including diagonally. If you're building a storage shed rather than something occupied by humans, code restrictions may be reduced; ask the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction. (My experience in framing is, admittedly, amateur/volunteer work.)

Comment: Depending on where you are (wind, seismic), you might need a shear wall, which you could theoretically design yourself. https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/framing/shear-walls-the-basics_o

Comment: Beyond that, there isn’t much to framing a long wall, except to say that you want good long lumber for plates, and to pay close attention to plumb when setting rafters or trusses.

Answer (score 3):

##### TL;DR Yes

I am taking this as a **Frame Challenge**. (Pun intended, of course, but I am actually serious here.) Framing new rooms inside a house - ask for details and get answers and ignore permits - fine with me. Framing an entire new building means, to me, that all significant issues with getting the building built in an *approved* manner are relevant.

Whether commercial or residential, in nearly all jurisdictions this requires a building permit and approval of plans. If you already have a building you can typically gut and redo the inside 10 times and nobody would care (even if technically permits are required) but with a new building it *will* be noticed. Doing it without permits and hoping for the best is *not* usually a good strategy because, depending on the jurisdiction and, possibly, the mood of the inspector, you could end up having to tear it all down even if it is nearly perfect with respect to building code.

In addition to framing & roofing issues (as you have already raised), other things to consider, which a formal design/plans will include, are:

- Foundation
- Earthquake, hurricane, etc. design. Varies a lot by jurisdiction - e.g., California will have more rules for earthquake resistance and Florida for hurricanes.
- Electrical - for almost anything beyond a storage shed, there are a lot of requirements - minimum number/maximum spacing of receptacles along each wall, minimum service required to the building, disconnect switch, ground rods, etc. Some of these are related to other things - e.g., many jurisdictions now require an "ufer ground" which is installed in the concrete foundation.
- Plumbing - there may be requirements for bathrooms, fire sprinklers, etc.
- Accessibility - there are minimum requirements for hallway widths, step heights, etc. In addition, commercial and multi-family residential buildings may require ramps or other wheelchair accessible features - all jurisdiction dependent.

Few of these things apply to a renovation. But a new building? *Every detail matters.*

Note that this does **not** remove the DIY aspect. You can get plans approved and then do all, or nearly all, of the work yourself. Exceptions vary - e.g., in many places some electrical work must be done by, or at least under the supervision of, a licensed electrician. But there are a lot more details for a real building (as opposed to a little storage shed) than many people realize.

Comment: I feel like you missed the point of the question.  It is around framing rigidity and strength of a 40 foot wall and if it is more complex that what was described

Comment: I answered a slightly different question. I am not a framing expert. Neither are you  - which is why you are asking the question. My concern is that when it comes to building a big structure that the building code (and related electrical, etc.) all comes into play.

Comment: Thank you.  I am very familiar with the codes, permits, state, city and county laws.  Looking for help with structural integrity of a 16x40 stick frame building.

Comment: Building code in general, and your local state/city/county rules should give you pretty good guidance as to the minimums needed for structural integrity, including any specifics for earthquake, hurricane, etc. where applicable.